# Injection of constructor attributes

Tags: java, spring, code-injection

I'm injecting in a list which will populate a map used within the class.

However when injecting in the flowing attribute:

```
private List<?> srcSystemIDList;
```

via the flowing XML:

```
<bean id="transformerHelper" class="com.common.TransformerHelper">
        <property name="srcSystemIDList" value="#{ T(java.util.Arrays).asList('6','57','92','93','7','108','106','105','98','52','122','9','26','51','101','102','118') }" />
</bean>
```

which is used by this method to set the map:

```
    public void srcSystemIDListInit()
{
        Object[] srcSystemArray = srcSystemIDList.toArray();
        int j;
        for(int i = 0; i< srcSystemArray.length; i = i+2)
        {
            j = i + 1;

            if(j < srcSystemArray.length)
            {
                srcSystemIDMap.put(srcSystemArray[i].toString(), srcSystemArray[j].toString());
            }
        }
}
```

I'm calling this via the constructor.

```
public TransformerHelper()
{
    srcSystemIDListInit();
}
```

However when the constructor calls the method the list is null throwing a null pointer exception.

How can I populate the map via the injected list

Comment: Did you try annotating `srcSystemIDList` with `@Resource`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do as Vikdor says, or you have a couple other approaches you can take too.

1. You could call this method, not from the constructor, but from your setter method `setSrcSystemIDList(...)`.  This will require the least work.  (But really, all of these suggestions are quite easy...)
2. You could implement the [`InitializingBean`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean.html) interface, and call your method from there.
3. You could annotate the method with [`@PostConstruct`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html).
4. You could add an [`init-method`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-lifecycle-initializingbean) attribute to your `bean` xml, which specifies the method to call.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to inject through constructor, then you should declare your constructor as

```
public TransformerHelper(List<?> srcSystemIDList)
{
    this.srcSystemIDList = srcSystemIDList;
    srcSystemIDListInit();
}
```

and your bean definition should be

```
<bean id="transformerHelper" class="com.common.TransformerHelper">
    <constructor-arg value="#{ T(java.util.Arrays).asList('6','57','92','93','7','108','106','105','98','52','122','9','26','51','101','102','118') }" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either call initialization from property setter:

```
public void setSrcSystemIDList(List<?> srcSystemIDList) {
    this.srcSystemIDList = srcSystemIDList;
    srcSystemIDListInit();
}
```

And use your spring configuration as is.

Or define a constructor with parameters:

```
public TransformerHelper(List<?> srcSystemIDList) {
    this.srcSystemIDList = srcSystemIDList;
    srcSystemIDListInit();
}
```

And transfer the list as constructor argument in spring configuration:

```
<bean id="transformerHelper" class="com.common.TransformerHelper">
       <constructor-arg value="#{  T(java.util.Arrays).asList('6','57','92','93','7','108','106','105','98','52','122','9','26','51','101','102','118') }" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at something like this

```
<bean id="transformerHelper" class="com.common.TransformerHelper">
    <constructor-arg><ref bean="yourListBean"></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Visit the [Source](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html) for more info.

Cheers,